# Save an image using Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Android development, and I decided on Kotlin and I still can't understand how it works. I am trying to develop a simple app with an image slider using  [Why Not! Image Carousel!](https://github.com/ImaginativeShohag/Why-Not-Image-Carousel#why-not-image-carousel)and I want to be able to save in my phone's storage the image that is currently showing in the slider, is there any way to do that? All the images that the slider shows are saved as Drawables.
I've spent days trying to do that and I don't know where to start, can someone help me with some hint of how I can do that please.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! A better title for your question would be "How to save a drawable to the phone storage on android?", because your problem is not really related to Kotlin. Also, please show some of the things that you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use that library, and I haven't done much with downloading images, so I can't give you a complete answer, but maybe set you in the right direction.

By browsing the source code of that library, I see it uses Glide to download images and put them in ImageViews. Glide uses either BitmapDrawable or GifDrawable as the type of the Drawable that it sets on the ImageView. As long as your views aren't Gifs, you should be able to get a Bitmap out of them. You could write a property to help with that:

```
/** The Bitmap in this ImageView, or null if it does not currently have one. */
val ImageView.bitmap: Bitmap? get() = (drawable as? BitmapDrawable)?.bitmap
```

There are many choices for how to go about saving a file. I'll just give a simple example. Saving a file should be done off the main thread, so this is a suspend function:

```
suspend fun Context.saveBitmap(fileName: String, bitmap: Bitmap) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val file = File(filesDir, fileName)
    file.outputStream.use {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, it)
    }
}
```

Usage, with some coroutine scope you should probably set up in your Application class so it can outlive your Activity(s) in case they are closed while a file is being saved:

```
val bitmap = someImageView.bitmap
if (bitmap!= null) {
    someScope.launch {
        try { 
            requireContext().saveBitmap("myFile.png", bitmap)
            // show success message to user
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // show error message to user
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the help, with this I have an idea of how to make it work, thanks again.

Comment: @yiver17 One more thing I should add. If you save the Bitmap from an ImageView that came from Glide, it probably has the resolution of whatever size it was on screen, meaning it would look blurry if zoomed. If that's a problem, you may want to consider re-downloading it at full resolution and saving that instead of working through the ImageView.